# Check day and difference time of a date

Tags: php, date, time

I have this date / time value (with timezone):

```
2019-10-22T17:00:00+02:00
```

Now I would like to check, which weekday this date is (for example: Monday)
and if this date has a difference of 1h between 16:00 o'clock and the date time.

How can I check the two factors as best practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`DateTimeImmutable`'s constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.construct.php) to parse the date string, [`DateTime#format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to format it / retrieve the week day, and [`DateTime#diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to fetch the difference:

```
$date_string = '2019-10-22T17:00:00+02:00';

$date = new \DateTimeImmutable($date_string);
$date_at_16 = $date->setTime(16, 0);

echo $date->format('l'), PHP_EOL;
echo $date->diff($date_at_16)->h;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/R7e9n**

Note that:

- I've used `DateTimeImmutable` which is just like `DateTime` except it cannot be modified, so `setTime` doesn't also modify the initial date,
- you should catch its constructor's potential thrown exception (if the format is invalid),
- it should be better to use `'N'` to retrieve the day of the week, as it's numerical and therefore more appropriate to store/compare (I've used `'l'` for the purpose of this little demo, to get the full name),
- if you need to know if it's 1 hour prior to or following 16 o'clock, you may check the `DateInterval#invert` flag (the date interval is what `DateTime#diff` returns).

Comment: thans a lot !! :)